# ¿Cómo se llaman los "Weighted-knuckle gloves" (o "sap gloves") en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

*[Weighted-knuckle gloves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted-knuckle_glove)*, también llamados *sap gloves*, son unos guantes de cuero o material sintético (por lo que son de "apariencia normal") que tienen refuerzos y protecciones metálicas entretejidas.

Estos guantes son usados para proteger las manos del portador durante una pelea (por ejemplo evitando cortes) y en algunos lugares son incluso considerados un arma blanca.

No sé si existe un término en español para referirse a estos guantes. A mí lo único que se me ocurre sería "guantes de motorista", porque algunos de estos guantes llevan protecciones extra en nudillos y otras áreas para proteger a los pilotos.

Sin embargo, "guantes de motorista" es demasiado genérico y llevaría a error, puesto que los guantes se pueden parecer al tener cierto tipo de refuerzo, pero la finalidad del guante es completamente distinta.

¿Alguien sabe cómo se denominan este tipo de guantes?

[image: SAP glove]

Comment: ¿Guantes reforzados?

Comment: @aparente001, sí y no. Buscando en goolge veo muchos tipos distintos, desde guantes de motorista a guantes anti-corte de otros tipos (como los que he visto usar a los pescaderos) o guantes de seguridad industrial. Los "weighted-knuckle" tienen otros fines distintos, pero igual caen en esa misma categoría...

Comment: Podrían ser "guantes tácticos". No sé si cubre todos los usos del término en inglés pero encaja bastante en la descripción.

Comment: @walen en su pregunta Diego dice: _"Estos guantes son usados para proteger las manos del portador durante una pelea"_. Aunque si que parece que normalmente las protecciones son de plástico. La verdad que antes de esta pregunta no sabía nada de todo esto.

Comment: El artículo de wikipedia creo que dice algo así como que es algo que un portero de discoteca usaría (entiendo que eso te hace pensar que es de cuestionable legalidad, independientemente de lo que realmente sea a nivel legal), pero pensad también en grupos como los GEO o los SWAT. Ellos no llevarían guantes normales, si no este tipo de guantes (ellos no tendrían problemas legales). Por lo que he visto en refuerzos similares en guantes de motorista, se favorecen materiales plásticos más que metálicos, que seguramente alivie el peso, como dice walen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de guantes se llaman:

- Guantes de combate
- [Guantes tácticos](http://www.multi-uniform.com/blog/seguridad/guantes-tacticos-por-que-son-necesarios)
- Guantes tácticos de combate

No encuentro en la RAE una definición de ellos pero para buscarlos en internet te debería salir.

Comment: La traducción literal de “Weighted-knuckle gloves” sería "Guantes con peso en los nudillos". Esto descarta los guantes de moto que llevan protecciones pero no peso. El peso está añadido para mejorar la lucha "cuerpo a cuerpo" o "mano a mano". Es verdad es que es fácil traducirlo.

Comment: @walen, creo que tienes razón, pero puede ser porque la terminología en inglés tampoco es clara y evidentemente al hacer la pregunta había cosas que yo no podía saber (posiblemente weigthed-knuckle y SAP sean cosas tan distintas como los términos en español). Buscando "guantes tácticos" he encontrado que: "los guantes tácticos no son de uso exclusivo para cuerpos militares y policiales. Su versatilidad hace que se conviertan en indispensables para actividades como caza, paintball o airsoft, o para trabajadores del sector industrial y bomberos,[...]"

Comment: Supongo que los "Weighted-knuckle gloves” son "de combate", mientras que los SAP son "tácticos", que tienen un uso más genércio (no siempre en combate, si no también en industria, bomberos, etc.).